# Stop header style inheriting theme CSS

Tags: css

I am using a plugin on a wordpress site which operates in light/dark mode where I can set the colours manually. However the headers are automatically inheriting the theme colours.

I have tried inspecting the code on the grid to try and isolate the class and create a custom CSS code to remove the inherit property.

The code that the issue exists in is

```
.tg-barking-mouse a:not([class*="tg-element-"]), 
.tg-barking-mouse a:not([class*="tg-element-"]):active, 
.tg-barking-mouse a:not([class*="tg-element-"]):focus, 
.tg-barking-mouse [class*="tg-element-"] *:not(del) {}
```

Within this bracket, the margin, padding, color etc exist. When I remove color it does exactly what I would like it to.

However when I paste the same code listed above in CSS and write color:none within the bracket, it doesn't seem to add to the element and overwrite the current color settings.

I believe there is a simple solution which will allow me to isolate the correct element but I'm not too sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Note that `color: none` is an invalid value for the color property http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/. Depending on what you're trying to achieve, you could set it to `transparent`/`inherit`/`initial`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your help, I was able to work it out by targetting h2 within the class and resolved the issue with the inherit property:

```
h2.tg-item-title {
color: inherit !important;
}
```

And it has inherited the plugin's text style rather than the Wordpress theme.

Answer (score 0):

Is it only the header that has the issue?If it is then you can use css to set your preferable color choice. try include important property like  `color: #000 !important;` or any color of your choice to see if it can do the trick.

Comment: It will be ignored because `color: none` is an invalid value for the color property. http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/

Comment: I saw that..I was so quick to miss out on my intended color but have corrected that.